# Users Profiles - Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have a server with 2012R2 OS installed.
Only two certain users are able to login normally, but all of the others have the problem below (Logging on locally and remotely, domain users and local users, admins or non-admins) (and we don't try to login at the same time):

When a user logs in, he gets a black screen without task bar or desktop, he only can press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to get that menu (Open task manager, change password,...).
I noticed an event in Events Viewer: ID=1530, Source: User Profile Service:

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other
>   applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The
>   applications or services that hold your registry file may not function
>   properly afterwards. No user action is required.

I tried a lot of ways, like:

- Restart User Profile Service
- Delete those users profiles from registry and advanced system settings.
- New users accounts
- Starting Explorer.exe from task manager
- Install all of the updates using Windows Update
- CMD> SFC /ScanNow
- CMD> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
- Bootrec.exe
- ...
  and restart after every way, but all of them without any help.

**An important note:** Once I was watching Task Manger (Users Tab) while one of the issued users was trying to login, I noticed that the Explorer.exe process started and ended immediately.

Comment: The trick is to find out why Explorer.exe is crashing. There should be an event in the application log for this. Take a look. I suggest downloading `autoruns` and disabling most of your non-Microsoft run items, plugins, context menu handlers, etc. I’m pretty sure you’ll get explorer to start. Then you can use a process of elimination. Also remove ANY security software for testing.

Comment: I could open EXPLORER from Task Manager > File > Run > Explorer (and check on WITH Administrative Privileges.

But I have to do that after every sign in process.

Comment: It's not solved yet.